# What is the origin story of The Phantasm and where did it get its powers from?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, mask-of-the-phantasm

(Sorry in advance for the vague phrasing.  I'm trying to avoid spoilers :-D )

In the movie Batman: Mask of The Phantasm, we see the Phantasm character exhibit supernatural powers like disappearing into a cloud of smoke and becoming transparent so weapons can pass through it.  Is there any explanation for how this was possible?  Was the character superhuman? Or was this a result of technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Andrea Beaumont, also known as [The Phantasm](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Phantasm), is a fictional character in the DC animated universe.**

- She was a martial arts expert and used high tech equipment, stage magic, slight of hand and technology to generate her fog which she used to misdirect and blind her enemies.
- The Phantasm wore a scythe-like prosthetic augmenting her hand to hand ability. The scythe was capable of cutting a handgun in two. She was an above average hand to hand combatant but preferred to use her smoke to give her an advantage.
- She also used a voice modulator to mask her voice, making it sound male as well.

There was another DC character, who was a member of the Teen Titans who also used the name of Phantasm who did have superhuman abilities. There was no relationship between the characters besides their masked appearances and draped cloaks.